# private method `total_price' called for #<LineItem:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, private, depot

I'm working with Depot tutorial, I'm having an issue when defining total price:
this is the  error I'm getting:  does  anyone knows  what is wrong with it?  thank you.

```
NoMethodError in Carts#show

Showing C:/pan/app/views/carts/show.html.erb where line #7 raised:

private method `total_price' called for #<LineItem:0x3ed2640>
Extracted source (around line #7):

4: <tr>
5: <td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
6: <td><%= item.product.brand %></td>
7: <td class="item_price" ><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
8: </tr>
9: <% end %>
10: <tr class="total_line" >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure this method's definition is not under `private` keyword in the LineItem class, otherwise it is considered private and is not allowed to be called outside the class.

Comment: thank you  @Semyon Perepelitsa,  I modified the LineItem class moving the method's definition above the "private" keyword and it works. thank you.